# Hibernate Search: Query only entity IDs when searching

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am implementing a fulltext search function via Hibernate Search and Lucene. The search looks like this and works quite well. My problem is that our entity classes are mostly very huge, so a search delivering 100 results takes too long, because querying the found entities is very time consuming.

When opening the form, I load the last 20 edited entities with a HQL query, which also took too long in the first place, so I created an entity containing only the fields I need to show in the resultlist and the ID of the actual entity. Only if the user clicks on a result to see it in detail, the actual entity is loaded. This sped up the querying time to 1/100 and less of the original time.

Is there a way to speed up the Hibernate Search querying in the same way, so I search for an entity, but only query the ID of the object and not the whole entity?

```
EntityManager em =  EntityManagerUtil.getEntityManager();

List<T> returnList=new ArrayList<>(); 

FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
em.getTransaction().begin();

QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(typeParameterClass).get();
TermMatchingContext onFields = qb.keyword().wildcard().onFields(getSearchFields()); 

BooleanJunction<BooleanJunction> bool = qb.bool();
org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = null;

String[] searchTerms = searchString.split("\\s+");
for (int j = 0; j < searchTerms.length; j++) {
    String currentTerm = searchTerms[j];
    bool.must(onFields.matching(currentTerm).createQuery());
}

query = bool.createQuery();

javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, typeParameterClass);
persistenceQuery.setMaxResults(100);

returnList = persistenceQuery.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Index Projections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#projections) to have your query return only selected attributes. The ID is an option:

```
javax.persistence.Query persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, typeParameterClass);
query.setProjection(ProjectionConstants.ID, [other fields...])
persistenceQuery.setMaxResults(100);
```

This will have your query return arrays. The first element of the array will contain the ID of each match.

You can load other fields as well, as long as they have been marked as stored using

```
@Field(store=Store.YES)
```

The ID is always stored, so you won't need to add this if you just want to project the IDs.

Incidentally, if you have such poor loading times there's something wrong with your mapping. I would guess that you have too many eager relations being loaded. A general recommendation is to map most of them to be lazy, and use also some 2nd level caching were appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You need org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery instead javax.persistence.Query

```
org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery persistenceQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(query, typeParameterClass);
persistenceQuery.setProjection(ProjectionConstants.ID);
persistenceQuery.setMaxResults(100);
```